# Read XML file with BOM in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, byte-order-mark

Powershell seems to be barfing on an xml file with a unicode BOM - the code:

```
$xml = [xml]{ get-content $filename }
```

blows up with 'Data at the root level is invalid'.

Is there an easy way to do this without fiddling around with the contents of the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to convert a script block into XML here. Use `()` instead of `{}`:

```
$xml  = [xml] (gc $filename)
```

In fact, the error message tells you as much already:

```
PS Home:\> $xml = [xml]{gc test.xml}
Cannot convert value "gc test.xml" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,
 position 1."
At line:1 char:13
+ $xml = [xml] <<<< {gc test.xml}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

You notice how the contents of the script block show up in the error message?

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. To be honest, I find those Powershell error messages almost indecipherable.

Comment: @Sam: The first part is the exception message. The second part the position in the script (or command line); after that follows a visual indication for that position. The last two lines you can safely ignore.

Comment: The world would be a better place it people would read their error messages.  ;)

Comment: @JasonMArcher - I didn't say I didn't read the message, I just didn't get anything useful out of it. FWIW my actual exception message was 268 lines longer than this.